# Bootstrap and <button> tag - event not firing first time- iPad only

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

We are using Twitter Bootstrap to pop up some modal windows and use some ajax calls. One problem we have run into concerns iPad devices.

We have this button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="reviewbutton" type="button">Submit Purchase Code</button>
```

which has its click event bound to this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reviewbutton").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.ourdomain.com/script.asp?purchase_code="+$("#purchase_code").val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          $("#review_form").modal("hide");
          if (data.indexOf('BADCODE') != -1) {
            $("#review_badcode").modal("show");
          } else if (data.indexOf('EMPTYCODE') != -1) {
            $("#review_badcode").modal("hide");
          } else if (data.indexOf('CODEOK') != -1) {
            alert("all ok");
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

When a purchase code is entered, we do a ajax lookup to see if the code is empty, malformed or otherwise valid. Our script.asp performs the lookup against a database and returns the appropriate code e.g. BADCODE in the case of a non-existent purchase code.

On iPad devices the click event does not fire until the button is clicked twice. On desktop browsers the code works perfectly. Is there a workaround, or is it a known bug? We have tried with BootStrap 2.3.1 and 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Does this button have a tooltip on it?
On Mobile devices you have to click an element for it to display it's tooltip. So if there is a tooltip the first click will display that. The button will have to be clicked a second time with the tooltip open in order for it to fire the click event.